# asp.net Output Encoding?

Tags: .net, asp.net, encoding

I'm not even sure i'm calling this the right thing. I'm just starting to get into ASP.Net and of course i'm starting to see syntax like <% "Code here" %>. So far i've seen <%: %>, <%= %>, <%# %>. Of course google doesn't like these symbols for searching so searching for help is futile :). Maybe this type of syntax is back from classic ASP (which i never used)? I don't know if there are any others than what i listed. Does anyone have a good link or can write up a good explanation. I also think it used in XML literals for vb.net. I also think its associated with certain functions like the "Eval" function.

Answer (score 3):

To be short,

- `<%# %>` is used for data binding (for example in a `ListView` where you want to specify how elements must be displayed on a page). If `this.Page.DataBind()` (or control-level binding) is not called, nothing will be displayed.
- `<%= %>` is used to display any string. `<% %>` on the other hand would let you to do any stuff you want, but you must use `Response.Write()` to output something.
- `<%: %>` is a new feature in .NET Framework 4.0 which does the same thing as `<%= %>`, but encodes output to be displayed as HTML.

This is called **inline tags**, so searching for "asp.net inline tag" may give you additional info.

Comment: @je5: yes, there are: `<%-- --%>` comment syntax, `<%@ %>` directives and the very strange `<%$ %>` used for expressions.